# How to pass category ids for joomla 3 cutom field

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, module, joomla3.0

I need to modify a joomla3 search module for searching 5 different search categories , there for i changed the module form.xml file and added five radio buttons , what i want is to assign specific category id for that radio buttons from database ,

Here the form.xml

```
       <field name="type" type="radio"
           label="COM_BANNERS_FIELD_TYPE_LABEL" description="COM_BANNERS_FIELD_TYPE_DESC"
           default="0" class="inputbox"
            >
        <option value="0">Classifields</option>
        <option value="1">Company</option>
        <option value="2">Government</option>
        <option value="3">Religious</option>
        <option value="4">Personal Names</option>
    </field>
```

heres the view/tmpl/default.php

```
  <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_(JomdirectoryHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute('')); ?>" method="post" name="jomdirectoryFormSearch" id="jomdirectoryFormSearch">


    <div class="control-group">

        <div class="controls1">
            <?= $form->getInput('type') ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default.php you have is not from Joomla's search module. It looks to be from something called JomDirectory. Joomla's search module looks like this:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/modules/mod_search/tmpl/default.php

To assign the category ID values and get them for the form you would actually put the category ID in the option value. Like this:

```
<field name="cat_id" type="radio"
           label="COM_BANNERS_FIELD_TYPE_LABEL" description="COM_BANNERS_FIELD_TYPE_DESC"
           default="0" class="inputbox"
            >
        <option value="58">Classifields</option> <!-- 58 is the category id -->
        <option value="13">Company</option> <!-- 13 is the cat id -->
        <option value="25">Government</option> <!-- etc -->
        <option value="39">Religious</option>
        <option value="47">Personal Names</option>
    </field>
```

Now to send that category to com_search (or whatever component you're actually using) you'll have to retrieve the category ID from the form post. In joomla you'll use JInput:

```
<?php

$input = JFactory::getApplication()->getInput();
$catid = $input->getInt('cat_id');

?>
```

You'll need to insert that $cat_id variable into the search query to have it return those results.

A few important notes:

1) Don't modify core Joomla. You could have done the form work with a template override. that said to do what you want to do requires some plugins to modify Joomla's search query (this way you aren't modifying core code)

2) There are extensions that do this properly with plugins that you could just install and use: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/12819

Comment: I want to get category id from database , since this category id is not fron joomla categories , its from this componenet call JomDirectory. Is there any poisiblity to get id from database table for this ?

Comment: Instead of using the dropdown type use the SQL type for your form field: http://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type

Comment: thanks , is there any possibility to use this for check box or radio button , if so how it be done

Comment: To do that you would need to basically create your own form type. Your best bet would be to fork the SQL type and then change it to render as checkboxes or radio.

Comment: You will have to create a new form type type and have it render the radios. You can see how to do that here: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type. You'll want to override the getInput method to be your SQL query to the DB and then use the results to generate the html for the select list.